# how to add column more than 10 at listbox?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

in my userform, there are combobox, textbox and listbox. here are the codes

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Me.BackColor = RGB(22, 54, 92)
Me.Label1.ForeColor = RGB(255, 255, 255)
Me.Label2.ForeColor = RGB(255, 255, 255)

Dim c As Integer
For c = 1 To 2
Me.ComboBox1.AddItem Sheet7.Cells(1, c).Value
Next

End Sub
```

here is the code for combobox

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    
    Dim c As Integer
    Dim column_headers
    column_headers = Array("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z", "AA", "AB", "AC", "AD", "AE", "AF", "AG", "AH", "AI", "AJ", "AK", "AL", "AM")
    
    For c = 1 To 39
    If Sheet7.Cells(1, c).Value = Me.ComboBox1.Value Then
    criterion = column_headers(c - 1)
    End If
    Next
    
    Me.ListBox1.Clear
    Me.TextBox1.Value = ""
    Me.TextBox1.SetFocus
    
End Sub
```

here is the code for textbox1

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
On Error Resume Next
If Me.TextBox1.Text = "" Then
Exit Sub
End If

Me.ListBox1.Clear
Dim r, last_row As Integer
last_row = Sheet7.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

With Me.ListBox1
    .ColumnCount = 39
End With

For r = 2 To last_row
    A = Len(Me.TextBox1.Text)
    If UCase(Left(Sheet7.Cells(r, criterion).Value, A)) = UCase(Me.TextBox1.Text) Then
    
    With Me.ListBox1
    .AddItem Sheet7.Cells(r, 1).Value
    .List(.ListCount - 1, 1) = Sheet7.Cells(r, 2).Value
    .List(.ListCount - 1, 2) = Sheet7.Cells(r, 3).Value
    .List(.ListCount - 1, 3) = Sheet7.Cells(r, 4).Value
    .List(.ListCount - 1, 4) = Sheet7.Cells(r, 5).Value
    .List(.ListCount - 1, 5) = Sheet7.Cells(r, 6).Value
    .List(.ListCount - 1, 6) = Sheet7.Cells(r, 7).Value
    .List(.ListCount - 1, 7) = Sheet7.Cells(r, 8).Value
    .List(.ListCount - 1, 8) = Sheet7.Cells(r, 9).Value
    .List(.ListCount - 1, 9) = Sheet7.Cells(r, 10).Value
    .List(.ListCount - 1, 10) = Sheet7.Cells(r, 11).Value
    .List(.ListCount - 1, 11) = Sheet7.Cells(r, 12).Value
    .List(.ListCount - 1, 12) = Sheet7.Cells(r, 13).Value
    .List(.ListCount - 1, 13) = Sheet7.Cells(r, 14).Value
    .List(.ListCount - 1, 14) = Sheet7.Cells(r, 15).Value
    .List(.ListCount - 1, 15) = Sheet7.Cells(r, 16).Value
    .List(.ListCount - 1, 16) = Sheet7.Cells(r, 17).Value
    .List(.ListCount - 1, 17) = Sheet7.Cells(r, 18).Value
    .List(.ListCount - 1, 18) = Sheet7.Cells(r, 19).Value
    .List(.ListCount - 1, 19) = Sheet7.Cells(r, 20).Value
    .List(.ListCount - 1, 20) = Sheet7.Cells(r, 21).Value
    .List(.ListCount - 1, 21) = Sheet7.Cells(r, 22).Value
    .List(.ListCount - 1, 22) = Sheet7.Cells(r, 23).Value
    .List(.ListCount - 1, 23) = Sheet7.Cells(r, 24).Value
    .List(.ListCount - 1, 24) = Sheet7.Cells(r, 25).Value
    .List(.ListCount - 1, 25) = Sheet7.Cells(r, 26).Value
    .List(.ListCount - 1, 26) = Sheet7.Cells(r, 27).Value
    .List(.ListCount - 1, 27) = Sheet7.Cells(r, 28).Value
    .List(.ListCount - 1, 28) = Sheet7.Cells(r, 29).Value
    .List(.ListCount - 1, 29) = Sheet7.Cells(r, 30).Value
    .List(.ListCount - 1, 30) = Sheet7.Cells(r, 31).Value
    .List(.ListCount - 1, 31) = Sheet7.Cells(r, 32).Value
    .List(.ListCount - 1, 32) = Sheet7.Cells(r, 33).Value
    .List(.ListCount - 1, 33) = Sheet7.Cells(r, 34).Value
    .List(.ListCount - 1, 34) = Sheet7.Cells(r, 35).Value
    .List(.ListCount - 1, 35) = Sheet7.Cells(r, 36).Value
    .List(.ListCount - 1, 36) = Sheet7.Cells(r, 37).Value
    .List(.ListCount - 1, 37) = Sheet7.Cells(r, 38).Value
    .List(.ListCount - 1, 38) = Sheet7.Cells(r, 39).Value
   
End If
Next r
End Sub
```

why the listbox on userform3 only shows 10 column? what's wrong? thank you

Comment: Add item only goes to 10, write to array first and then use .list to fill the listbox

Comment: make a sample code please :(

Comment: What `criterion` is and where receive it a value? If receiving, what value does it have, being the same for all rows/cases?

Comment: I follow this step from video https://youtu.be/9PuVRE7ARKA

Comment: I do not care too much about "your video", no offence. Do you know what `criterion` is, or not?  If not, look again to the video and try clarifying this aspect. Then, your code cannot work even for any number of columns, since you have `With Me.ListBox1` and no `End With`. We do not play here with code. You should prove that you know what you try doing and be able to answer clarification questions. If you want us looking to videos in order to help you, I am afraid you are in a wrong place, no offence...

Answer (score 1):

Please, using the next adapted code. You need to have a `Private` variable on top of the form code module (in the declarations area):

```
  Private criterion As String
```

Then, copy the next code event instead of yours:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
 If Me.TextBox1.Text = "" Then Exit Sub

 Me.ListBox1.Clear
 Dim r As Long, last_row As Long, a As Long
 last_row = Sheet7.cells(rows.count, 2).End(xlUp).row 'last row of Sheet7

 Me.ListBox1.ColumnCount = 39

 Dim arrFin, critCount As Long, k As Long, j As Long
 ReDim arrFin(1 To 39, 1 To last_row)  'redim the array to keep the necessary data

 For r = 2 To last_row                      'iterate between the sheet range
    a = Len(Me.TextBox1.Text)        'place the TextBox1 text in the variable
    If UCase(left(Sheet7.cells(r, criterion).Value, a)) = UCase(Me.TextBox1.Text) Then 'check if the string starts with chars from txtB1
        k = k + 1                                    'increment the rows variable
        For j = 1 To UBound(arrFin)
            arrFin(j, k) = Sheet7.cells(r, j) 'load the array to place in the list box
        Next j
   End If
 Next r
 
  If k > 0 Then 'if a match has been found
     ReDim Preserve arrFin(1 To 39, 1 To k) 'eliminate the emply elements of the array
     If k = 1 Then
         transpose2D arrFin            'transposing a 2D array with a row, a 1D array will result...
         Me.ListBox1.List = arrFin  'drop the built array content in the list box
     Else
         Me.ListBox1.List = Application.Transpose(arrFin) 'drop the transposed array content
    End If
  End If
End Sub

Sub transpose2D(ByRef arr) 'transform the 2D one column in 2D one row:
   Dim i As Long, arr2D, k As Long
   ReDim arr2D(1 To 1, 1 To UBound(arr) + 1)
   For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
        k = k + 1
        arr2D(1, k) = arr(i, 1)
   Next
   arr = arr2D
End Sub
```

When place a question **you need to understand the code you show**. Looking to the other procedures i deduced that the recommended global/private variable must exist...

I commented al the code lines which you may not understand. If something still not clear enough, do not hesitate to ask for clarifications.

Answer (score 0):

instead of the additem:

```
With Me.ListBox1
    .List = Sheet7.Cells(2, 2).Resize(last_row - 1, 38).Value
    .ColumnCount = UBound(.List, 2) + 1
End With
```

Comment: why is not working ? :(